# CakePHP cache query in table beforeFind

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

We can cache the query in the controller, but I wonder if we can do that in the table itself, that will be more usable as this:

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary)
{
    $query->cache(function ($query) {
        return 'some_key';
    });
}
```

I tested it, DebugKit showed that write is happened once every time I refresh the page but no read occurred anytime.

I even tried with this:

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary)
{
    $query->cache('some_key', 'default');
}
```

Comment: Plz try to add cache key or cache config like : $query->cache('cache_key');

$query->cache('cache_key', 'configName');

Comment: @AkshaySharma I didt but the same happened

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9768

Comment: thanks @ndm I will follow the opened issue